# How should I approach getting ms-excel to recognize strings such as "/deg" as a shortcut?

Tags: vba, excel

Is this even feasible?  It would be really useful to be able to just type /deg and have Excel auto-replace that phrase with the degree symbol, but I'm not sure how I would approach something like this.  My VBA/macro knowledge is a bit lacking

Comment: Alt-0176 is the same amount of keystrokes as /deg. Otherwise, a simple search and replace in the Worksheet_Change event would do it.

Comment: Are you processing angles or temperature ??

Answer (score 1):

Here is a tiny trick........say we enter **127/deg** in a cell:

[image]

If we select the cell(s) and run this tiny macro:

```
Sub AMatterOfDegree()
    Dim r As Range, v As String

    For Each r In Selection
        v = r.Text
        If Right(v, 4) = "/deg" Then
            r.Value = Left(v, Len(v) - 4)
            r.NumberFormat = "General" & ChrW(176)
        End If
    Next r

End Sub
```

we will have:

[image]

This is a real numeric value with the degree symbol in the format.  The cell can now be used arithmetically.

Answer (score 0):

If you add references to autocorrect you can replace them as you type.

If you want to add all the standard math autocorrect values to the normal autocorrect there is a way to do it [here](http://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/wiki/office_2013_release-excel/how-to-use-math-autocorrect-in-excel/dadf030c-2ba3-4080-9383-3050705792cf).  Apparently math autocorrect doesn't really work in excel.

Autocorrect can be found under file>options>proofing